# Change the routes for models in laravel 8 php artisan auth

Tags: php, laravel

I am making application with tutorial. At the very beginning, I ran the command php artisan ui:auth which created a login and registration page for me. Initially my models (eg Users) were in the App/Models/Users folder but I had to change their location to /App/Users because only then application it worked according to the tutorial. The login page itself works, but when I click the 'login' button I get an error:

> Error
> Class '\App\Models\User' not found

> Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::createModel
> C:\xampp\htdocs\testowa4\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider.php:186

186 line is in the function:

```
public function createModel()
{
    $class = '\\'.ltrim($this->model, '\\');
    return new $class;   //186 line 

}
```

How to change model paths for these files? I need them outside the Models folder. Is there any way to refresh the routes or something like that?

Comment: Welcome to SO ... check your `config/auth.php` file and adjust the FQCN there

Comment: If you move the model files and change the `namespace` from `App\Models` to `App` accordingly then it should work. If it doesn't work you can try running `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: The namespace in all files is changed and every page of my application works fine. There is only a problem with pages after clicking the login button. I tried composer dump-autoload and still the same error

Comment: ok i changed the config/auth.php file and it works! thank you so much

Comment: @lagbox in login page it works, but in register page i have still the same error. What can i do to change the route for register too?

Comment: its not a route ... but you would have to go into the controller for registration and change the class that is being used